# Javascript regex match string also with space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to match, of style contains, for example, color. This is string:

```
<a href="#" style="margin:50px;color:2;">test</a>
```

And my regex:

```
/(color:(.);)/
```

It works now, what I need to do, so it will also match `color: 2;`?

Comment: Why are you trying to deconstruct style strings like this? Anyway, the answer is you need to find the magic regexp character which will match a space, and--imagine this--it's a space! If you want the space to be optional, you follow it with a `?`, which is a feature documented on the first page of any regexp introduction you'll find on the web. That first page will also talk about another operator, the asterisk, which matches zero or more of something, so ` *` is zero or more spaces, which is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I want to remove each style, except of color, font-size... and some more. I am newbie in regex, so I start asking by the simple one.

Comment: To manipulate styles, manipulate the styles directly, as in `element.style.fontSize = '';`. CSS is a language, and it's never a good idea to try to parse or rewrite anything but the simplest language with regexps. They will break, and be hard to maintain. If you want to experiment with regexps, start with some sample problems which are more suited to regexps.

Comment: I cannot, I have issue, that TinyMCE has styles on the elements. When you copy styled text from TinyMCE, it will flag that and insert as HTML, when it is from another website, or word, whatever, it will paste as plain text. I have compelted that, but when I have selected item, copied it, pasted it in editor, there are all styles (from reset, another CSS etc...) si I have to remove each style, that is not directly added via TinyMCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\s*` to match optional space characters:

```
/(color:\s*(.);)/
```

(.) will match only a single character color.
If you want to match another colors with more characters, use following regular expression:

```
/(color:\s*([^\s;]+)\s*;)/
```

(used `\S` to match non-space character)

Comment: Thanks for fast response! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: What about `color : 2`? What about `background-color: 2`? What about 'color: 2 ;'? Also, your regexp only matches colors of a single character.

Comment: @torazaburo, Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Also thanks for update, I wanted to ask about that. But that not work, when `color` is not at the end.

Comment: @debute, Do you mean additional spaces after the color name? how about this? `/(color:\s*(\S+)\s*;)/`

Comment: @falsetru nope, just before name. But when you have string like `<a href="#" style="color:red;margin:50px;background-color:red;font-size:15px;">test</a>` then match is a whole `style=""`.

Comment: @debute, You can use negated character class to exclude `;`: `/(color:\s*([^\s;]+)\s*;)/`

Comment: This will greedily eat up everything up to the final semicolon in the string.